# How to aggregate totals after every day

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table that looks like this.

```
      Date        Hospital Total Operations Errors
2001-10-01      Hospital A             1101      0
2001-10-01      Hospital B               32      0
2001-10-02      Hospital A             1184      0
2001-10-02      Hospital B               74      0
2001-10-03      Hospital A             1350      0
2001-10-03      Hospital B               72      0
2001-10-04      Hospital A             1364      0
2001-10-04      Hospital B              232      0
2001-10-05      Hospital A             1345      0
2001-10-05      Hospital B              212      0
```

And want to accrue totals for each hospital every day and add them to that specific day's row so that my final table can look like this.

```
      Date        Hospital Total Operations Errors Aggregated Operations Aggregated Errors
2001-10-01      Hospital A             1101      0                  1101                 0
2001-10-01      Hospital B               32      0                    32                 0
2001-10-02      Hospital A             1184      0                  2285                 0
2001-10-02      Hospital B               74      0                   106                 0
2001-10-03      Hospital A             1350      0                  3635                 0
2001-10-03      Hospital B               72      0                   178                 0
2001-10-04      Hospital A             1364      0                  4999                 0
2001-10-04      Hospital B              232      0                   410                 0
2001-10-05      Hospital A             1345      0                  6344                 0
2001-10-05      Hospital B              212      0                   622                 0
```

Is there a way to do that in python? Any assistance is truly appreciated.

Comment: `groupby()` and `cumsum()`. Could you please use `df.to_dict()` and paste the output here so I can take it as input and try the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby()` and `cumsum()` as I suggested previously in the comments:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2001-10-01','2001-10-01','2001-10-02','2001-10-02','2001-10-03','2001-10-03','2001-10-04','2001-10-04'],
                   'Hospital':['Hospital A','Hospital B','Hospital A','Hospital B','Hospital A','Hospital B','Hospital A','Hospital B'],
                   'Total Operations':[1101,32,1184,74,1350,72,1364,232],
                   'Errors':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
df['Aggreated Operations'] = df.groupby(['Hospital'])['Total Operations'].cumsum()
df['Aggreated Erros'] = df.groupby(['Hospital'])['Errors'].cumsum()
print(df)
```

This will output:

```
         Date    Hospital  ...  Aggreated Operations  Aggreated Erros
0  2001-10-01  Hospital A  ...                  1101                0
1  2001-10-01  Hospital B  ...                    32                0
2  2001-10-02  Hospital A  ...                  2285                0
3  2001-10-02  Hospital B  ...                   106                0
4  2001-10-03  Hospital A  ...                  3635                0
5  2001-10-03  Hospital B  ...                   178                0
6  2001-10-04  Hospital A  ...                  4999                0
7  2001-10-04  Hospital B  ...                   410                0
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should work.

```
df['Aggregated Operations'] = df.groupby('Hospital')['Total Operations'].cumsum()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.join(df.sort_values(by=['Date','Hospital']).groupby(['Hospital']).cumsum(), rsuffix=' Aggregated')
```

Output

```
         Date    Hospital  Total Operations  Errors  Total Operations Aggregated  Errors Aggregated
0  2001-10-01  Hospital A              1101       0                         1101                  0
1  2001-10-01  Hospital B                32       0                           32                  0
2  2001-10-02  Hospital A              1184       0                         2285                  0
3  2001-10-02  Hospital B                74       0                          106                  0
4  2001-10-03  Hospital A              1350       0                         3635                  0
5  2001-10-03  Hospital B                72       0                          178                  0
6  2001-10-04  Hospital A              1364       0                         4999                  0
7  2001-10-04  Hospital B               232       0                          410                  0
8  2001-10-05  Hospital A              1345       0                         6344                  0
9  2001-10-05  Hospital B               212       0                          622                  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple use of `transform()` and concat results to original df

```
df = pd.concat([df, df.groupby(['Hospital']).transform("cumsum").add_suffix(" Cumulative")], axis=1)
```